# How to split a dataframe and make result become a dataframe itself

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I have split my dataframe into a 70/30 split, I then need to be able to call the 70% split for a further function.

```
df = pd.read_csv(('data.csv'), names = header_list)
trainingdata = df.sample(frac=0.7)
testingdata = df.drop(trainingdata.index)

X = trainingdata.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy().astype('float32')
Y = trainingdata.iloc[:,0].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1).astype('float32')
print(Y.shape)
print(X.shape)
```

above is my code to split the dataframe, and assign the x and y values. x = all rows and columns besides the first one, y = only first column and all rows. I cant call 'df' as it will call every single row before I performed the 70% split, I specifically need the split for NN training.

How do I make 'trainingdata' its own dataframe so I can then call it in my function?

Comment: is it not? what problems are you facing when you call it in your function?

Comment: i get the error "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (329, 1), indices imply (470, 1)" - this is when i use pd.DataFrame to call my original dataframe, I was just wondering how i call my split dataframe. Ive tried numpy.array[trainingdata], and pd.trainingdata, but neither of these work. am i maybe using the wrong syntax to call it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - it was an argument later in my code causing the issue, a section of code needed to index and it was using my df function to call the original dataframe.